# How do electricians calculate the maximum allowed on circuit breakers if the current is measured in AC?

Tags: ac

Correct me if I’m wrong but the majority of electronics circuit operate of a 3V3 constant DC voltage, which the current would be reasonably stable draw apart from charging up capacitors, chips loading up, so adding up current is relatively simple ie. i1 + i2 ... etc. =iTotal  but most of appliances are powered from mains drawing an AC current which means a sin waveform, so the equation becomes more difficult i1sin + i2sin .... etc. , so to answer my own question would I be right in saying that circuit breakers are rated for total AC current?

Comment: They are rated for RMS current.

Comment: @Andyaka are appliances like air conditioners rated for RMS current draw ?

Comment: Yes, the rated current for **mains connections** are RMS currents.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie to find the total current do you sum together the appliances in series ?

Comment: The appliances aren't connected in series, they're **in parallel**. You need to add up all currents so a 1 A refrigerator and a 5 A coffee grinder makes 1 + 5 = 6 A. That's the current that would be drawn. The choice of circuit breaker should be based on what wiring thickness is used. The electrician doesn't know your appliances. The electrician does know how much current the mains wires in the house can handle.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie:  +1 for the "1A fridge" and the "5A coffee grinder."

Comment: Small fridge (2 beers) but industrial grade coffee grinder ;-) Other people might have different priorities ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The breakers are chosen for fire safety and the standard practice is to have a current rating near the power entry on an imprinted label to define the RMS current for safety to calculate the branch current requirements.

The electrician simply adds all these ratings to ensure the wire and breaker ratings  “meet or exceed” the local standards and use the sum total by a safe margin to prevent nuisance trips from high inrush motor surges.

So breaker ratings do not include inrush current, which for charging up caps or starting motors  can be ~10x nominal , when starting at peak Vac, unless reduced by design.

These vary with input voltage range and within the range so a worst case rating is used on the label, not nominal.

The device must have its own protection if it a low power device.

Answer (score 0):

RMS Current is what heats up wire or any ohmic resistance like RDs on in mosfets        .PVC copper wire has max safe temperature ratings so the RMS current is the most important parameter here.In AC circuits the RMS current is generally greater than the Average  Rectified current .With pure DC the Average current is the RMS current .For a pure Sine wave the RMS current is 1.11 times the average Rectified   current .This factor is called the form factor and can be regarded as a figure of merit where 1 is ideal .Bad harmonic rich waveforms can have form factors of 2 or more .This is one of several reasons why breakers have to be specified higher than one would initially think . A real example of this is a 100 Amp single  phase battery charger that despite having its average rectified current strictly    limited to 100 amps blew a 120 amp test fuse .

Comment: For a sine wave, average is zero. Maybe you mean the average of one half cycle?

Comment: @ Andyaka .Taking the half cycle is a good way of avoiding the zero issue

Answer (score 0):

Circuit breakers are regulated by electricity building norms. The idea is to break the circuit soon enough, before nothing gets overheated, for ex. the wires inside the walls. The currents are in those norms said as RMS values. That means an amperage of DC which would have the same thermal effect in wires and resistors. If we say RMS AC current is 1 ampere, the sinusoidal current has peak value 1,41 A which is the RMS current multiplied by sqrt(2).

Electricity building norms state maximum allowed circuit breaker ratings vs wire length, wire cross section and how  the wires are insulated and placed inside walls, floors, assembly tubes etc...